# onFocus not getting cursor position with selectionStart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selection-api

I am trying to get the caret position of where the user has clicked on a text box. I want to add a certain text at the position the user clicks the input. I am trying to do it in the `onFocus` method of the `input`. However, `e.target.selectionStart` gives me `0` always.

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "hello"
    };
  }

  onFocus = e => {
    console.log(e.target.id);
    console.log(e.target.selectionStart); // receiving only 0 here
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        id="my-input"
        onChange={this.onChange}
        value={this.state.value}
        onFocus={this.onFocus}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/6x623x50r

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the cursor position value `onFocus` event, do it `onMouseUp` event. onFocus is not called when the input is focussed and you click somewhere else within the same input.

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "hello"
    };
  }

  onMouseUp = e => {
    console.log(e.target.id);
    console.log(e.target.selectionStart);
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        id="my-input"
        onChange={this.onChange}
        value={this.state.value}
        onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

[Working codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1on0qjkp37)

There is a bug getting `selectionStart` onFocus event, you can check the issue [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=526516)